# Sending a mail with htmlbody with VBA Excel works, but when I use Display the line breaks (</br>) dissapear

Tags: excel, vba

As the title says. Here is part of the code I wrote, perhaps I made a mistake.

So when I use .Send in the code, the mail is sent correctly and the line breaks are in the mail.

When I use .Display, the linebreaks dissapear (the

divisions still work) and do not reappear when I send the mail from Outlook. Only using

tags is an option, but I don't always want an empty line between sentences.

```
.htmlBody = "<Goedemorgen, </br> </br>" & _
             DatePart("d", DateAdd("d", daysUntilDelivery, Date)) & " " & MonthName(DatePart("m", DateAdd("d", daysUntilDelivery, Date))) & " (wk. " & weekNumber & ").</br>" & _
            .Display
```

I left out some of the code since it's basically just more of the same.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: First of all, whatever Goedemorgen is, it's not html, so remove the `<` before it,. second of all, it's not `</br>`, it's `<br>`

Comment: @braX That was indeed a small mistake. Using <br> fixes the problem, I was actually trying to use <br/>, which also works. It's just been a while since I used HTML and that's why I messed up. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, goedemorgen means good morning! If you resubmit your comment as an answer I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, whatever Goedemorgen is, it's not html, so remove the `<` before it. Second of all, it's not `</br>`, it's `<br>` (or `<br/>`)